# Prepackaging FireFox for Distribution

Tags: firefox, portable

I install FireFox for a lot of my clients and tend to install a set of plugins and configurations for the browser. Is there a way to package Firefox with it's settings and plugins and make it easier to distribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can Mozzila; have release a tool called:

> Institutional Deployment

It advertised to be able to pre-configure the following:

```
Deploy options for Firefox (prefs.js, userchrome.css, usercontent.css)
Deploy extensions/themes
Deploy settings for extensions (prefs.js)
Lock down some of the settings (updates to extensions/ app, uninstallation of extensions)
Deploy search-plugins (eg. a custom search-plugin for a Knowledgebase in your Org.)
Deploy bookmarks
Deploy user-interface customisations. (like toolbar settings)
A custom namespace icon (Windows only)
Customise the help page(s).
Name of your Org in the title bar.
```

You can find more information at the Mozzilla [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/) about tools they offer

---

*The content in the wiki is to large to transcribe into Super User answer*